# What can be tiled by T-tetrominoes?

Tags: co.combinatorics, tiling

The T-tetromino is a T-shaped figure made of four unit squares.
An $m\times n$ rectangle can be tiled by T-tetrominoes if and **only if** both $m$ and $n$ are multiples of 4. This was proved in a 1965 paper by D.W.Walkup, and the proof was "hands on".

Some "algebraic" tricks like colouring or tiling groups can prove that $mn$ must be a multiple of 8, but they do not seem to rule out the cases like $99\times 200$ and $100\times 102$.

I wonder whether a better proof of D.W.Walkup's theorem is known today. By "better" I mean applicable to non-rectangular regions as well. For example, is there a way to determine what 6-gons (8-gons, ...) admit tiling by T-tetrominoes?

Comment: The paper "Tiling rectangles with T-tetrominoes" by Korn and Pak seems to present some progress for non-rectangular simply-connected regions, mainly Theorem 11 in section 8. It doesn't seem like they have a complete answer though. 

http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.70.6847

Comment: See also Korn's thesis, "Geometric and algebraic properties of polyomino tilings".

Answer (score 25):

There are only partial answers to this question.  First, one can *prove* that Walkup's result cannot be proved using coloring arguments (I think I did this in [New horizons](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~pak/papers/tilesurvey.ps) paper, but the setting is formalized in the [Ribbon tile invariants](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~pak/papers/tile.pdf) paper). Second, Walkup's proof uses an easy induction argument, and it extends to regions with sides multiples of 4.  Third, I am pretty sure you can classify all 6- and 8-gons tileable by T-tetrominoes.  This won't be conceptual.  Why do it then?

Now, motivated by the quest to find a better proof, I made a "local move connectivity" conjecture saying that every two T-tetromino tilings of a simply connected region are connected by a series of moves involving either two T-tetrominoes or four T-tetrominoes (forming a $4\times 4$ square).  Usually, the "conceptual proof" comes from some kind of *height function* argument which also proves the local move connectivity.  Now, Mike Korn in his [thesis](http://dspace.mit.edu/handle/1721.1/16628) disproved this by a simple construction.  One can ask if the *Conway group* approach in full generality can prove something like what you are asking.  You need to compute $F_2/\langle tile~words\rangle$ (see [Conway-Lagarias](http://linkinghub.elsevier.com/retrieve/pii/0097316590900574) paper, "New horizons" or Korn's thesis).  We did not do that, but I won't be very optimistic - it is a bit of a miracle when this approach works out.

Mike and I were still able to prove the conjecture (by a height function argument) for rectangles and the above mentioned 4-multiple regions, but that proof assumes Walkup's theorem.  Independently this was [established](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~kmakaryc/pdf/tetro.pdf) by Makarychev brothers, using a related but somewhat different argument (in Russian, based on connection to the six-vertex model).  In fact, in a [followup paper](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~pak/papers/tutte7color.pdf) we use Walkup's theorem as a definition of the graphs in which the number of claw partitions is "nice".  Anyway, hope this helps.

UPDATE:  I just remembered that Michael Reid also did the T-tetromino computation (as well as many other computations) [here](http://www.math.ucf.edu/~reid/Research/Tilehomotopy/tilehomotopy.pdf).

Comment: Do any of these results provide new obstructions for tilings (as opposed to studying the structure of the set of possible tilings of some regions)? Is there any non-rectangular region which is proved to be non-tilable, but not for colouring reason and not because of some local obstruction (like "there is only one way to cover this square, but then no way to cover that")?


Comment: If the question is whether one can extend Walkup's result to "nice" non-rectangular regions, the answer is yes, but only by using his idea again.  If the question is whether our local connectivity results imply any non-tileability results, the answer is also yes, but the regions would be rather ugly and actually hard to construct.  If the question is whether one should hope for a general algebraic approach, the answer is probably no, or at least that's my intuition.  